# How can I change the key on expo aab build or how to change the sha1 key in app singing in google play console project without using android studio?

Tags: react-native, expo, google-play, google-play-console

I have created an expo project with my previous account and uploaded it in google play console and the app is live. I created same project with my company's account with new generated key and new name and everything.

Now I want to upload a new app version taken from my new expo account but I cant. It says
Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again. Your App Bundle is expected to be signed with the certificate with fingerprint:
SHA1: (first one)
but the certificate used to sign the App Bundle you uploaded has fingerprint:
SHA1: (second one)

How can I change the key on expo build aab file, or how to change in sha1 key in app singing in google play project without using android studio?

I created the same app in another expo account but when I upload it in google play console app realess it doesn't work

Comment: Please provide some code